# Enable Dialogflow ES Sentiment Analysis by API

Tags: dialogflow-es

How can I enable "Sentiment Analysis" on a Dialogflow Essentials agent through an API request?

Answer (score 0):

You may enable **Dialogflow ES Sentiment Analysis** by providing `sentimentAnalysisRequestConfig` field in the **Request JSON body** of your API request and setting the `analyzeQueryTextSentiment` to **true** similar to below sample testing.

Sample **request.json**:

```json
{
  "queryParams": {
    "sentimentAnalysisRequestConfig": {
      "analyzeQueryTextSentiment": true
    }
  },
  "queryInput": {
    "text": {
      "text": "please reserve an amazing meeting room for six people",
      "languageCode": "en-US"
    }
  }
}
```

Sample API request via **cURL** command:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
"https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/project-id/agent/sessions/123456789:detectIntent"
```

Output:
[image]

You may refer to this [Dialogflow ES - Detect Intent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/sentiment#detect_intent) documentation for more details.